# File name presists in Dir() function over multiple sessions

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code in a Excel VBA macro and it seems like its persisting values between sessions. The issue is with the BtnUpdate_Click event, the message box doesnt trigger even if the file path in NewDataFilePath is invalid.

```
Public NewDataFilePath As String

Private Sub BtnFileBrowse_Click()
    Dim fdlg As FileDialog
    Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    fdlg.Title = "Select New Dataset"
    fdlg.Filters.Clear
    fdlg.Filters.Add "Excel Files Only", "*.xls; *.xlsx"
    fdlg.Show

    If fdlg.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        TxtFilePath = fdlg.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    NewDataFilePath = TxtFilePath.Text

End Sub

Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click()
    Dim a As String
    a = Dir(NewDataFilePath)

    If Not Dir(NewDataFilePath) <> "" Then
        MsgBox """ & NewDataFilePath & "" is not a valid file path"
    End If

End Sub
```

I added the string a in the event handler to try and debug the code and its showing me some interesting results:

*I have a breakpoint on the if statement in BtnUpdate_Click.*

[image: File path is selected]

Then i stop debugging the macro and re-run it. if i invoke BtnUpdate_Click without selecting another file the Dir() function seems to keep the last file name:

[image: File path is blank]

Any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: Are you using global variables?

Comment: Are you using constants?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs The only code i have in the Macro is above, I'm using "Public NewDataFilePath As String" but as per the screenshots the value in it doesn't persist when i re run the macro.

Comment: I think you are missing the path (from the debug screenshots you posted). A  file name is not enough, you cannot invoke Dir function on a file name without a path.

Comment: You say *then I stop debugging...*  if by that you mean you click the stop button on the VBA toolbar, that will clear the Public variables.

Comment: Use TxtFilePath = fdlg.FileName

Comment: just to say that you can simply code `If Dir(NewDataFilePath) = "" Then` instead of `If Not Dir(NewDataFilePath) <> "" Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is no persistence of any variable value once you stop a macro

While the observed behavior is due to the following:

1) `FileDialog` object keeps the last path chosen in its `IntialFileName` property

2) `Dir(path)` function with an empty string as "path" would return the first file in the `IntialFileName` path stored by last `FileDialog` run

so when you re-run the macro:

- `NewDataFilePath` is an empty string
- `a = Dir(NewDataFilePath)`, would return the first file in the `IntialFileName` path matching the filters (if any)

What above as the answer to your question

While you could consider the following "nuance" of your code:

```
Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click()
    If NewDataFilePath <> "" Then 'if 'NewDataFilePath' has been set
        Dim a As String
        a = Dir(NewDataFilePath)

        If Not Dir(NewDataFilePath) <> "" Then  MsgBox """ & NewDataFilePath & "" is not a valid file path"

    Else 'otherwise
            MsgBox "No file path specified!", vbCritical ' inform the user to do so
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Public NewDataFilePath As String

Private Sub BtnFileBrowse_Click()
Dim fdlg As FileDialog

Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
fdlg.Title = "Select New Dataset"
fdlg.Filters.Clear
fdlg.Filters.Add "Excel Files Only", "*.xls; *.xlsx"
fdlg.Show

If fdlg.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    NewDataFilePath = fdlg.SelectedItems(1)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click()
Dim a As String

a = Dir(NewDataFilePath)

If DoesFileExist(NewDataFilePath) And NewDataFilePath <> "" Then
    MsgBox NewDataFilePath & " is a valid file path"
Else
    MsgBox NewDataFilePath & " NOT a valid file path"
End If
End Sub

Function DoesFileExist(filePath) As Boolean
DoesFileExist = Dir(filePath) <> ""
End Function
```